# Wait for element to fadeOut IF the element is visible

Tags: jquery

This is likely a duplicate but I couldn't find it, so here we are.
I have 2 fullscreen overlays to be displayed with a fading transition upon pressing on some buttons. The logic behind should be:

if (layerA is visible)

then ( fadeOut layerA; wait until the transition is complete; fadeIn layerB; )

else ( fadeIn layerB )

The code is actually quite straightforward:

```
if (layerA.is(':visible')) {
  layerA.fadeOut("slow", function () { layerB.fadeIn("slow"); }
else { layerB.fadeIn("slow"); }
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried CSS @keyframes?

Comment: could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Will give a quick demo, so you want LayerA to fadeOut and then layerB to fadeIn?

Comment: yes, but LayerA could be visible or not, we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about `CSS`, so please make your on style. I think you are expecting something to work like below demo.

```js
$('.overlay2').hide();
$('.overlay1').fadeOut('800');
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.overlay2').fadeIn('slow');
}, 800);
```

```css
.overlay1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: .5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.overlay2 {
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay1">This is overlay 1</div>
<div class="overlay2">This is overlay 2</div>
```

Or simply as:

```js
$('.overlay2').hide();
$('.overlay1').fadeOut('800');
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.overlay2').fadeIn('slow');
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay1">This is overlay 1</div>
<div class="overlay2">This is overlay 2</div>
```

Comment: No, this is hiding the 2 layers one after the other, what I expect is to swap them, but there's no need to hide one of them when it's already hidden.

Comment: please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're after, but this is a simple FadeIn & FadeOut with two elements using JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#picOne').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
  $('#picTwo').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

```css
#picOne,
#picTwo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#pics {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pics">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" width="200" height="100" id="picOne" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/39811/pexels-photo-39811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" width="200" height="100" id="picTwo" />
</div>
```